# How to compare element state in a web page, using Perl binding with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: perl, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I need to know how to validate the changing state of any element in a web page, using Selenium WebDriver with Perl binding. The following is the use case:

1. I'm using an application, which gets the changing status of a discovered machine, in the background.
2. Suppose there is a web element named 'Machine State'.
3. The state of this element varies, based on the actual machine state: Running/Stopping/Stopped.
4. The XPath ID for this state locator (Running/Stopping/Stopped) is always constant, irrespective of any state of the machine.

How can I validate each status of the locator in the web page?

Please let me know if I need to explain the scenario in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is more about what strategy to use than how to code that in Perl, right?

An obvious solution would be to have it monitor a machine whose state you control and alter it during the test so you can verify every state.

I'm thinking it would look something like this, where the classes are a naive way of making a distinction. I've listed each possible state once.

```
<div id="state" class="green">started</div>
<div id="state" class="yellow">stopping</div>
<div id="state" class="red">stopped</div>
```

So to check that all three states are reachable under the same id, you have to make the data your application gets represent that.

If you cannot control an actual machine, mock it during the Selenium test. Telling you how to do that is out of scope for this answer (and possibly this Stack Exchange). I suggest if you want in-depth information about QAing strategy you should ask on the [Software Quality Assurance SE](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hello Simbabque, thanks for your reply. You are close to what exactly i wanted to ask. I actually have a question on how can i handle such web element in selenium webdriver, where for any fixed element locator, values gets changes always and i need to validate those changed values in different times. I basically need a snippet of selenium code with perl binding to work on such web elements. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: @Manas what do you mean by _gets changes always_ and _in different times_? How does that work? The page is loaded in the browser, and there are events happening that make the page change? And then you want to revalidate? Can you please explain that in more detail in the question. I believe we need a bit more technical depths about what is going on to figure out how to do that. I am not using Selenium so I won't be able to give you code, but again, I can try to give you strategy if I have sufficient information.